# Convert XAML-objects to a SoftwareBitmap

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have some control in XAML that I would like to convert to a `SoftwareBitmap`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, this code do exactly this:

```
static async Task<SoftwareBitmap> CreateSoftwareBitmap(FrameworkElement uielement)
{
    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);

    IBuffer pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    var bitmap = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(pixels,
                                                     BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                                     renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                                                     renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                                                     BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Do like this if you want to show the `SoftwareBitmap` on an `Image` control:

```
var softwareBitmap = await CreateSoftwareBitmap(MyXamlControl);
var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();

await source.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap);
MyImageControl.Source = source;
```